# "Too much recursion" on submit by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, onsubmit

This is my custom submit function with a validation. Its showing "Too much recursion" after I click on Submit.

```js
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){
    var validateError = ''; 
    var id = '';
    var fieldError = [];

    $('#searchform :input:text').each(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        validateError = jQuery.fn.validationEngine.loadValidation(document.getElementById(id));
        if (validateError) { 
            fieldError.push(id); 
        }
    });

    if (fieldError.length != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("form#searchform").submit();
        return true;
    }
});
});
```

My form is taking too much time for submit. In console I can see my validation Ajax method is calling infinitely .  How I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that if the form is valid, you call `.submit()` on it, which calls your callback once more, which calls `.submit()` again, etc., etc. and you get an infinite recursion loop.

Just remove

```
else {
    $("form#searchform" ).submit();
    return true;
}
```

altogether and it should work (your callback won't return anything and the browser will proceed with the default form submit behaviour).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Shall I need to add e.preventDefault(); if validation fail ?

Comment: No, you don't need it, since you already have `return false;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the resubmission within the submit:

change this:

```
else {
    $("form#searchform").submit();
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
else {
    return true;
}
```

or *just remove it altogether* as the default (if you do not return anything) is also to continue the submit.

You are already correctly returning false when the validation fails, so no need to use `e.preventDefault()`. `return false` does the same as both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

i.e. this is correct:

```
if (fieldError.length != 0) {
    return false;
}
```

although you can test for non-zero length with just this:

```
if (fieldError.length) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to submit form in else statement:

change your statement:

```
else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please check that there is not already an *exact duplicate* of your answer before posting. :)